# Why can't Google Chrome update without someone logged in?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, updates, auto-updates

I have a number of Windows 10 machines in an AD environment that host Chrome.  If someone logs into the machine and goes about their business, it appears as if Chrome runs its updates just fine.  If no one is logged in for a day or more, however, the update task just never runs successfully, even though Windows seems to have it as a time-based schedule.  If I log into those same machines and open the "About" tab, I see it launches updates right away.

The main issue is that our vulnerability scanners definitely pick up on the lack of updates, and the need to go to these machines for manual checks is not tenable at scale.

Does anyone have a similar experience, and if so is there a resolution?  As far as I can tell this is *not* expected behavior from Chrome based on documentation, but I don't believe I have done anything to alter how it would check for updates by default.

Comment: Check against the article [Manage Chrome updates (Chrome Browser Cloud Management)](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9838774?hl=en#zippy=%2Cturn-on-auto-updates-recommended). Check also that you have running these system services: `GoogIeChromeEIevationService`, `gupdate` and `gupdatem`  (you can use [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and enter `google` in the search field).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; I do have those three services from what I can tell but I did notice that the Elevation Service is Manual while all others are Automatic.  Is this supposed to be the case?

Comment: Mine is also on manual.